# package org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings does not exist

Tags: android, qt

While I'm trying to build Hue Qt example android(https://github.com/BradyBrenot/huestacean), stuck at this error.
I'm new in Qt. My Qt version `5.12.0` and Android studio `3.3.2`

`error: package org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings does not exist`

[image]

What Should I do solve this error?
Thanks in advance.

Addition.

Now I tried with QtCreator.  But build error with `Unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras`

[image]

Addition#2.

After addging `Android Kit` at preference, error message became as below

```
The installed SDK tools version (26.1.1) does not include Gradle scripts. The minimum Qt version required for Gradle build to work is 5.9.0/5.6.3
```

[image]

Comment: You have to use Qt Creator to compile

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I updated content with QtCreator as above.  Do you have any idea about `Unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras`

Comment: How have you installed Qt ?, if you have used the online installer then you must open it again a search the android module, select it and install it

Comment: yes, I installed Qt 5.12.0.  And all related android is installed.

Comment: I already saw where the problem is, when you open the project you have selected it as a project for DESKTOP, instead you have to reopen the project and choose ANDROID

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my basic level question.  I added android kit.  then tried build again.  Now `The installed SDK tools version (26.1.1) does not include Gradle scripts. The minimum Qt version required for Gradle build to work is 5.9.0/5.6.3` occur.

Comment: If you are trying to use android in Qt you should at least know how to program in android with android-studio, so the message should not be unknown, you have to install the appropriate version of gradle. goodbye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
import org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtService;
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-services.html